# NoMethodError, undefined method login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a simple app for login/logout, and i had an error:

```
NoMethodError in WelcomeController#create 
undefined method `login' for #<User:0x3dc02c0>
```

this is my usermodel

```
 def self.authenticate(pass)
    user = find_by_pass(pass)   
    if user.nil?
      return nil
    else
      return user
    end
    end
```

this is my controller

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:pass])
      login user
      redirect_to root_url                                                     
    else
   render 'index'
    end
    end
```

this is my welcomehelper

```
 def login(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

this is my application controller

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
include WelcomeHelper
```

please help me to fix that :)

Comment: It seems to be really messed up. It doesn't work directly because `login` is defined as `User` class method, and you try to use it as an instance method. But this piece of code has other serious problems. First of all, you seem not to encrypt passwords in any way, which is security issue.

Comment: the problem is that login is a helper method.  Helper methods are not available in controllers.  though there are other issues with your code, moving the login method to application_controller will solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

**application_controller:**

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
def login(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

and use all the remaining methods as you have defined

Comment: it's doesn't work, but i'm trying different way. Anyway thank you for your help!